# Будьте добры подскажите как из СSV файла сформировать базу данных в java

Tags: java, sql, парсер, csv

```
 Название, закупочная цена, группа, объем, состав, шт.
===========================================================
"Вода минеральная Хорошо", 9.99, "минеральные воды", 0.3, "вода минеральная, лечебно-столовая", 570
"Вода минеральная Хорошо", 15.47, "минеральные воды", 1.5, "вода минеральная, лечебно-столовая", 412
"Сок Богач Грейпфрутовый", 22.00, "соки", 0.95, "вода, сок грейпфрутовый концентрированный, фруктоза, лимонная кислота", 156
"Енерджи бум Плюс", 24.15, "прочие напитки", 0.33, "вода, лимонная кислота, ароматизатор Яблоко, Е-345, Е-120, Е-630, Е-632, краситель Вишня", 78

и для такого типа: название, закупочная цена, классификация (вино, крепкий алкоголь, пиво, ликеры), объем, крепкость напитка, наличие шт.
=====================================================
"Мартини Биссе", "ликеры", 205.00, 1.0, 13%, 12
"Два моря", 195.00, "вино", 0.75, 12%, 0
"Пиво Одесское Новое", 13.25, "пиво", 0.5, 4.3%, 120
"Красная испанка", 80.00, "вино", 0.75, 14%, 92




Напишите программу для эмуляции работы магазина по продаже напитков на языке Java/C#. При выполнении задания пользуйтесь системами контроля версий (GitHub, Bitbucket…).
Для проверки необходимо будет предоставить ссылку на репозиторий с выполненным заданием.

Магазин продает алкогольные и безалкогольные напитки. Для алкогольных напитков база данных содержит следующую информацию: название, закупочная цена, классификация (вино, крепкий алкоголь, пиво, ликеры), объем, крепкость напитка, наличие шт.; для неалкогольных напитков:  название, закупочная цена, группа (минеральные воды, соки, прочие напитки), объем, состав, наличие шт.
Информация об ассортименте товара (база данных) хранится в виде CSV файла, содержимое которого имеет примерно следующий вид:

"Вода минеральная Хорошо", 9.99, "минеральные воды", 0.3, "вода минеральная, лечебно-столовая", 570
"Вода минеральная Хорошо", 15.47, "минеральные воды", 1.5, "вода минеральная, лечебно-столовая", 412
"Пиво Одесское Новое", 13.25, "пиво", 0.5, 4.3%, 120
"Красная испанка", 80.00, "вино", 0.75, 14%, 92
"Сок Богач Грейпфрутовый", 22.00, "соки", 0.95, "вода, сок грейпфрутовый концентрированный, фруктоза, лимонная кислота", 156
"Енерджи бум Плюс", 24.15, "прочие напитки", 0.33, "вода, лимонная кислота, ароматизатор Яблоко, Е-345, Е-120, Е-630, Е-632, краситель Вишня", 78
"Мартини Биссе", "ликеры", 205.00, 1.0, 13%, 12
"Два моря", 195.00, "вино", 0.75, 12%, 0

В процессе продажи товаров выполняется наценка стоимости по следующим правилам:

●     Стандартная наценка составляет 10% от закупочной цены
●     В выходные дни наценка составляет 15% от закупочной цены
●     В период с 18:00 до 20:00 наценка составляет 8% от закупочной цены (выходные и будние дни)
●     При продаже от двух единиц товара за раз наценка на следующие единицы товара снижается до 7% от закупочной цены

Магазин работает с 08:00 до 21:00 каждый день.

В конце каждого дня производится дозакупка товара в размере 150 шт. для каждой позиции, наличие которой составляет меньше 10 шт.

Необходимо написать программу, которая будет эмулировать работу данного магазина и после эмуляции работы одного месяца (30 дней) подготовит отчет о прибыли:

●     В начале работы программа загружает существующий CSV файл для получения информации об ассортименте и текущем наличии товаров.
●     Каждый час в магазин приходит от 1 до 10 покупателей, которые приобретают от 0 до 10 единиц случайных товаров. Цена продажи товаров формируется в соответствии с описанными выше правилами наценки стоимости. Информация о каждой продаже выводится в консоль в процессе работы программы (что продано, цена продажи каждой единицы, какие правила наценки применены).
●     По окончании рабочего дня производится дозакупка недостающего товара.
●     После эмуляции 30 дней программа сохраняет в текстовый файл отчет, который содержит информацию:
●     Количество проданного товара для каждой позиции;
●     Количество дозакупленного товара для каждой позиции;
●     Прибыль магазина от продаж (сумма продаж минус себестоимость проданного товара);
●     Затраченные средства на дозакупку товара.
●     По окончании работы программы CSV файл перезаписывается (обновляется информация о наличии товара на конец работы программы).
```

Comment: Вам нужно помочь составить схему БД или придумать способ генерировать схему автоматически из рандомных данных?

Comment: я хочу перенести это все в sql только по полочка, так что бы я мог потом безпрепятственно работь с этими данными

Comment: То есть в вас есть готовая БД и вам надо просто разобрать данные из CSV. Я все верно понял?

Comment: "Мартини Биссе", "ликеры", 205.00, 1.0, 13%, 12 - это и есть элемент БД, но я не знаю как все эти строки правильно розпарсить и закинуть в Бд по полочкам - я начинающий (

Comment: Сейчас напишу вам проект для примера

Comment: Сори. Не увидел что на Java. Могу только на C#.

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста это за неделю зделать вообще реально ?

Comment: Это реально сделать за пару часов. У меня уже практически готов проект на C#, но вам нужно на Java.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий... То, что вы выложили Ваше тестовое задание - хорошо, но это все таки Ваше задание и дано, чтобы определить Ваш уровень. Изначально у вас есть 2 типа данных. У них четко просматривается общий родитель, поскольку различия лишь в одном пункте: состав-крепость, то строийе 3 класса. 1 родитель и 2 наследника. Подключаете хибернейт, а еще лучше в связке с Spring Data, получаете крисавую ORM. Есть неколько вариантов предствления и обработки наследования в БД, хибернейтом можно настроить любую. Вопрос в том, говорит ли Вам о чем-то слова наследование, хибернейт и спринг...